# C++11: What happens if you don't call join() for std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

Given below:

```
void test() 
{
  std::chrono::seconds dura( 20 );
  std::this_thread::sleep_for( dura );
}

int main()
{
  std::thread th1(test);
  std::chrono::seconds dura( 5 );
  std::this_thread::sleep_for( dura );
  return 0;
}
```

`main` will exit after 5 seconds, what will happen to `th1` that's still executing?

Does it continue executing until completion even if the `th1` thread object you defined in `main` goes out of scope and gets destroyed?

Does `th1` simply sits there after it's finished executing or somehow gets cleaned up when the program terminates?

What if the thread was created in a function, not `main` - does the thread stays around until the program terminates or when the function goes out of scope?

Is it safe to simply not call `join` for a thread if you want some type of timeout behavior on the thread?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: @Drop Because that's no reliable way of learning about *guarantees*.

Comment: @dyp neither asking on Stackoverflow is. By compiling and running this 5-line exmple, at least he could find a clue. There is only one source of guarantees -- a standard.

Comment: @Drop *"neither asking on Stackoverflow is"* Well, a good SO answer in my opinion quotes a reliable source (as you did). Not even the Standard itself however is a completely reliable source, since it contains defects. Compiler providers will often deviate from a literal interpretation e.g. to incorporate proposed resolutions of defect reports. Because of the existence of Undefined Behaviour, I think it's not good practice to learn about guarantees by trying things out.

Comment: I think "why don't you try it?" is a perfectly valid response, the question would be improved if it showed the OP had bothered to run some experiments before asking. "I tried it and my program terminated, is that expected?" is a better question than "what would happen if I did this?" It's not like we're talking about eating some unidentified berries found growing wild, C++11 compilers are freely available and running experiments is easy and educational.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I think dyp was referring to the general case, I have seen many questions where people make that comment and it would lead to the wrong conclusion, so I have to agree it is not helpful advice. In this specific case it probably would have lead to a more interesting question but we are assuming the OP has a machine they are free to install things on or knows about online compilers. I have been shocked at how many well informed developers don't know about online compilers.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you have not detached or joined a thread when the destructor is called it will call `std::terminate`, we can see this by going to the [draft  C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) we see that section `30.3.1.3` *thread destructor* says:

> If joinable(), calls std::terminate(). Otherwise, has no effects. [
>   Note: Either implicitly detaching or joining a joinable() thread in
>   its destructor could result in difficult to debug correctness (for
>   detach) or performance (for join) bugs encountered only when an
>   exception is raised. Thus the programmer must ensure that the
>   destructor is never executed while the thread is still joinable. —end
>   note ]

as for a rationale for this behavior we can find a good summary in [(Not) using std::thread](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/11/14/not-using-stdthread/)

> Why does the destructor of a joinable thread have to call
>   std::terminate? After all, the destructor could join with the child
>   thread, or it could detach from the child thread, or it could cancel
>   the thread. In short, you cannot join in the destructor as this would
>   result in unexpected (not indicated explicitly in the code) program
>   freeze in case f2 throws.

and an example follows and also says:

> You cannot detach as it would risk the situation where main thread
>   leaves the scope which the child thread was launched in, and the child
>   thread keeps running and keeps references to the scope that is already
>   gone.

The article references [N2802: A plea to reconsider detach-on-destruction for thread objects](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2802.html) which is argument against the previous proposal which was detach on destruction if joinable and it notes that one of the two alternatives would be to join which could lead to deadlocks the other alternative is what we have today which is `std::terminate` on destruction if joinable.

Comment: "or it could cancel the thread..." What does it mean to "cancel" a std::thread? By the way it's worth noting that C++20 adds jthread that joins on destruction.

Answer (score 6):

`std::thread::~thread()`

> If *this has an associated thread (`joinable() == true`), `std::terminate()` is called

Source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread

This means that program like this is not at all well-formed or safe.

Note, however, that `boost::thread::~thread()` calls `detach()` instead in this case.
(as user *dyp* stated in comments, this behavior is deprecated in more recent versions)

You could always workaround this using RAII. Just wrap your thread inside another class, that will have desired behavior on destruction.

Comment: That behaviour of boost is deprecated: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.destructor

Comment: @dyp Cool! May I add it in my answer? ;)

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, you must explicitly specify 'what happens' when the newly created thread goes out of scope (our it's dtor is called). Sometimes, when we are sure that the main thread, is continuing, and our threads are acting as 'pipeline', it is safe to 'detach()' them; and sometimes when we are waiting for our WORKER threads to complete their operations, we 'join()' them.

As [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.destructor) says, the programmer must ensure that the destructor is never executed while the thread is still joinable.

Specify your multi-threaded strategy. In this example, `std::terminate()` is called.